# How to make an ADD and REMOVE rows in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a form where user has to add products.
I have made the form like this
**JSFIDDLE** -- >http://jsfiddle.net/FC7df/2/

When i add one product the name index must increment eg: for 2nd pname name must be `name="pname[1]"` .Like wise same for others.
I know how to add the rows but the problem is if some one adds 4 products and then removes the 2nd one ,, the name index sequence of the remaining products becomes like this -- >

- 1st product - `name = "pname[0]"`
- 2nd product - `name = "pname[2]"`**//this should be changed to pname[1]**
- 3rd product - `name = "pname[3]"`**//and this should be changed to pname[2]**

How to do that in jquery so that the index sequence remains organised no matter which element is removed ?

Comment: Where is your jQuery code?

Comment: You forgot to place jQuery in your fiddle :)

Comment: Based on the fiddle, it's your row that needs the index such that `<tr rowindex=0 >` adding and removing rows should renumber the `tr` elements of your table which can be easily accomplished using jquery's `.each()`

Comment: updated the fiddle . you can add the elements . i am confused abt remove part .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should not care about re-sequencing of html elements. 
Please check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FC7df/5/)

```
$(document.body).on("click",".remove",function(){
  i--;
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  var remaningTR = $("table tr");
    console.log("i",i)
    console.log("remaningTR",remaningTR)
  for(var j=0;j<=i;j++){
      console.log("came in")
    var inputElem = $(remaningTR[j+1]).find("input[type=text]");
    console.log("inputElem",inputElem)
    $(inputElem[0]).attr("name","pname["+ j +"]");
    $(inputElem[1]).attr("name","mno["+ j +"]");
    $(inputElem[2]).attr("name","price["+ j +"]");
  }  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate the elements and update the index when you add or remove items. Something like this:

```
$('table').find('input[name^="pname"]').each(function(i){
    $(this).prop({ name: 'pname[' + i + ']' }); // etc...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want to remove an element use array.splice(index, 1);In that way index sequence will remain organised
http://plnkr.co/edit/N950rfO2o5xaxUhU6rvQ?p=preview

Comment: can u give a jsfiddle example ?

Answer (score 0):

When remove event is triggered simply go trough rows ($.each) and replace on every input element name index with iterator.